# Is there a way to turn off the add module buttons?

Tags: 2sxc

Having installed 2SXC, every pane gets 3 buttons on hoover.
Is it possible to turn those off?

scenario 1: a pane is quite small and instead of clicking a shopping basket, you'll add another module

scenario 2: a customer is not a hard core tech and adds 80 modules in a pane (true story)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it - you need an attribute in the dom-area which should behave non-default. This allows you to enable / disable it in certain areas as you need it. It's documented here: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/Html-Js-%24quickE

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix via CSS:

```
/* hide the 2sxc content pane controls */

.sc-content-block-menu.sc-content-block-quick-insert {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```